# Is there any reason to use a WaitHandle over a bool to flag for cancellation?

Tags: .net, multithreading, synchronization, waithandle

I've inherited a bit of threaded code, and upon reviewing it, I'm finding structures like this (within a background thread method):

```
private ManualResetEvent stopEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

private void Run_Thread() {
    while (!stopEvent.WaitOne(0, true)) {
        // code here
    }
}
```

Usually there's a public or private `Stop()` method, like so:

```
public void Stop() {
    stopEvent.Set();
    bgThread.Join();
}
```

My question is this: What is served by using a wait handle here? It seems as though this is done to ensure that signalling for a stop is an atomic operation, but I thought writing to a boolean was atomic anyway. If that's the case, is there any reason not to just use the following:

```
private void Run_Thread() {
    while(!stop) {
        // code here
    }
}

public void Stop() { 
    stop = true;
    bgThread.Join();
}
```

Comment: Your stop method needs a call to `bgThread.Join()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Writing to a `bool` variable is indeed atomic, but unless the variable is also *volatile* (or you introduce some other synchronization) then it might not be visible from other threads. Such problems can be hard to track down and reproduce.

For example, on my x64 laptop, the following program stops correctly. On my x86 netbook, it hangs forever. (Both compiled with `csc /o+ Test.cs`).

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

class Test
{
    static bool stop = false;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Thread(CountLots).Start();
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        stop = true;
        Console.WriteLine("Finished...");
    }    

    static void CountLots()
    {
        long total = 0;
        while (!stop)
        {
            total++;
        }
    }
}
```

In this particular case it seems reasonable to use a volatile flag - although if you're using .NET 4 it would be better to use the Task cancellation mechanisms :)

Of course normally a better reason for using something other than a flag is if you want to wait for some condition - whether that's "is there a new item" or "have I been cancelled" (or both) - without tight-looping.

Comment: Thanks Jon - unfortunately I'm still stuck in .NET 3.5; otherwise I'd have completely re-written this mess.

Comment: Another question - you mention using `volatile` - are there any downsides to marking a variable as `volatile`?

Comment: you can not use that variable by "ref" anymore, and you lose possible CLR optimizations, but that's what "volatile" is about :)

Comment: @vtortola: You *can* use the variable as a `ref` parameter, but you'll get a warning and the volatility won't be preserved within the called method.

Comment: That's what I wanted to mean, I don't explain myself very well :P

Answer (score 1):

You can't do a controlled / blocking "wait" on a bool (although you probably don't need to, and Monitor might be more light-weight anyway).

As a cancel *flag* bool is fine, but you might want to make the bool volatile to prevent register cache being an issue.

Comment: That's the thing - this code doesn't actually *wait* on this wait handle, it just uses it as a flag. +1 for the `volatile` tip.

Answer (score 1):

Just using a bool won't work, you have to declare it *volatile* to tell the code generator that it should not store the value in a CPU register.  The exact time that the thread will see the value set to true is unpredictable, it heavily depends on the kind of CPU your code runs on.

Ugly details, ones you can ignore when you use a WaitHandle.

The last argument should be False btw.

Comment: It's `true` in the code-base I've got - to be perfectly honest I don't understand the argument, so I didn't want to deviate from what's in the code.

Comment: Just omit it, there's an overload for WaitOne() that takes just the timeout.  It got added in .NET 2.0 service pack 1 because so many programmers didn't know what it meant either and got it wrong.